# Setting views as their own delegates swift

Tags: ios, swift, delegates, uicollectionview

I'm thinking of subclassing a `UICollectionView` and setting it up as its own delegate and writing my own delegate wrapper. Is it safe in terms of memory? (The object will be pointing to itself)

Comment: There is no memory problem but it will probably lead to hard-to-use or hard-to-maintain code. The collection view will need to coordinate with other objects at some point, and without a delegate that will be difficult.

Comment: It's a fascinating question - we do this all the time and for me it's the only way to go.  If you need a full container view (which is the alternative), do that.  But if it's just a typical agent - a little collection view that looks after itself - for what possible reason would you wrap it in another class that gets the delegates?

Comment: Regarding Aaron's point .. @AaronBrager , as you say the thing in question "will need to coordinate with other objects at some point" ...... but then, that is true of every single thing on every single screen I've ever done, heh!  Sure, just like any control, it would be a complex thing with likely delegates and so on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be possible as already mentioned but to follow MVC and other similar good development patterns it's a good idea to keep the data source and delegates separate from a view. Otherwise you will be heading down a path of difficult to test code and mixing the boundaries between data and views. The impact of this may not be obvious with your current plans but may be later. 
By subclassing the collection view you will also loose the view life cycle call backs including viewDidLoad and viewWillAppear etc which could be useful to set up your view. At least subclass the UICollectionViewController if you want to implement your own data source and delegate wrapper. That way you can customise the behaviour without breaking good practices.

Comment: But code patterns are fractal. Say you're the team at apple that builds "UISlider" or "UILabel" or "UIButton".  Of course "from the outside" it's just a UISlider.  But *within* UISlider you have ........... the MVC pattern!  However, once you get to the "outside" .............. it's just a control.  (With delegates and so on.)  Similarly, say I make a "CityList" (which, in reality, is a collection view - but the other team members couldn't care less about that).  ***From the outside*** you indeed ***want it to be*** a monolithic "V" view thing.

Answer (score 3):

I think there is no problem in that (memory wise) as the delegate and dataSource  vaiables are `weak`

```
weak public var delegate: UICollectionViewDelegate?
weak public var dataSource: UICollectionViewDataSource?
```

Answer (score 1):

As long as you have another class that has a strong reference to the view, you should have no problems. The view will be kept in memory until the parent class releases it, or the parent class itself is disposed.